# Could not link boost file system

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, boost, linker

I use Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. I cannot build my project.

I've downloaded boost archive, extracted it to `C:\boost`.

Opened `Developer Command Line for VS2012` and executed `bootstrap.bat` and `bjam.exe` in boost directory (took about 5 minutes).

In my project, i've added `C:\boost` to additional include directories and `C:\boost\stage\lib` to additional library directories (in build settings).

If i write in my code:

```
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
```

I get linkage error:

```
Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_58.lib'
```

Project type is: Win32 application (CLR support).

Other boost headers seems to work well on other project.
What should i learn about linking boost what i am missing?

Comment: Do you have any boost_filesystem_vc110* file in your stage\lib folder?

Comment: @marom bunch of static libs with file names starting with `libboost` and no `filesystem`.

Comment: This means that filesystem library has not been build.

Comment: Try b2 --with-filesystem --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-12.0 stage and see if you get the lib files in stage\lib

Comment: @marom, are you sure `msvc-12.0` is `vs12` and not `vc120` (which is vs13). trying..

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I posted my command line (which is for MSVC2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by running this command in `c:\boost` (thanks @marom):

```
b2.exe --with-filesystem --toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage
```